# Zwischen dir und mir oder du und ich

Tags: preposition, dative, pronoun, accusative, wechselpraeposition

Ich habe überhaupt nicht verstanden, was richtig ist. Im Buch steht, dass „zwischen" eine Präposition ist, und dass es die Regel gibt, dass man bei Bewegung Akkusativ verwendet und sonst Dativ.

Aber für Pronomen habe ich keine Regel gefunden. Es gibt ein Buch mit dem Titel „zwischen du und ich", es gibt aber auch einen Liedtitel wie „zwischen dir und mir"

Kann mir jemand mir erklären, was richtig ist?

Comment: Vielen sehr Dank, für die Antwort und Erklärung. Wenn ich fragen stellen darf, möchte ich fragen. Was ist eigentlich Bewegung ist? Bedeutet Bewegung das Laufen? Oder Bewegung ist die Arbeit? Z.B. wenn ich auf den Tisch etwas stelle. Heißt das, ich bin zum Tisch gekommen und danach gestellt. Was passiert wenn ich schon beim Tisch und stellt etwas. Ich meinte, wir sagen, ich arbeite am Computer. Kann man sagen ich arbeite an den Computer? Komische Frage, aber ich möchte wissen.

Answer (score 8):

Alle Regeln, die du zitierst, sind richtig. Dir scheint nur nicht klar zu sein, wie sie hier anzuwenden sind.

1. Es stimmt, dass man für Richtungen in der Regel den Akkusativ verwendet, und für Orte in der Regel den Dativ.
2. Diese Regel lässt sich auch auf *zwischen* anwenden: (Dabei ist es gleichgültig, ob Nomen oder Pronomen mit *zwischen* verbunden werden).

- *Zwischen dir<sup>Dativ</sup> und mir<sup>Dativ</sup>* bezeichnet einen Ort:

  > Der Tisch steht zwischen dir und mir.
- *Zwischen dich<sup>Akkusativ</sup> und mich<sup>Akkusativ</sup>* bezeichnet eine Bewegung in eine Richtung:

  > Der Ball fällt zwischen dich und mich.
- *Zwischen du<sup>Nominativ</sup> und ich<sup>Nominativ</sup>* ist nicht korrekt. Es kann aber sein, dass die Wortgruppe lautet: *zwischen Du<sup>Dativ</sup> und Ich<sup>Dativ</sup>*, wobei *Du* und *Ich* nicht Personalpronomen sind, sondern Abstrakta, also Nomen, die abstrakte Gegenstände bezeichnen, die hier im Dativ stehen würden, und die im Nominativ *das Ich*, und *das Du* heißen würden. (So spricht man etwa in der Gedichtanalyse vom *lyrischen Ich*.) Der folgende Satz etwa würde ausdrücken, dass zwei Menschen per se verschieden sind:

  > Zwischen Du und Ich liegt eine unüberwindliche Kluft des Andersseins.

  Dabei kann es sein, dass *Du* und *Ich* nicht großgeschrieben werden. Das entspricht zwar nicht den Rechtschreibregeln, aber es gibt wohl eine entsprechende Sprachwandel-Tendenz, die aus Personalpronomen abgeleiteten Abstrakta ebenfalls klein zu schreiben.

3. Darüberhinaus gibt es noch Präpositionen, die bestimmte Fälle verlangen, sodass einem die Regel "Akkusativ für Bewegung in eine Richtung, Dativ für einen Ort" nicht weiterhilft. Diese Präpositionen muss man auswendig lernen.

Comment: Weiteres Beispiel (Die Zeit, 12.11.1965, Nr. 46): *Das Gespräch zwischen Du und Ich bedarf keiner übergeordneten Vermittlung.*

Comment: Eine weitere Möglichkeit wäre, dass "du" und "ich" zwar Personalpronomen sind, die aber als Zitat der entsprechenden (im Nominativ stehenden) Anrede gedacht (und ggf. geschrieben) sind. Einen Titel wie "Zwischen 'du' und 'ich'" könnte ich mir beispielsweise als treffend vorstellen für einen Text, in dem man Egoismus und Altruismus gegenüberstellt.

Answer (score 1):

Der genau Buchtitel lautet nicht »zwischen du und ich«. Den Titel so zu schreiben wäre falsch, denn diese Schreibweise behauptet unmissverständlich: »Alle Wörter werden kleingeschrieben!« was in weiterer Folge bedeutet: »Keines der Wörter ist ein Substantiv!« Und genau das ist falsch. Die Groß-/Kleinschreibung sollte man in der deutschen Sprache sehr ernst nehmen!

Auf dem Cover des Buches steht leider

> ZWISCHEN **DU** UND **ICH**

Das ist zwar eine korrekte Schreibweise, aber die Frage der Groß-/Kleinschreibung wird dabei der Interpretation des Lesers überlassen.

In anderen Quellen steht aber der korrekte Titel:

> Zwischen Du und Ich

Zum Beispiel in der [Lesejury](https://www.lesejury.de/mirna-funk/buecher/zwischen-du-und-ich/9783423282673), bei [Google Books](https://books.google.at/books?id=kEAAEAAAQBAJ&dq=zwischen%20du%20und%20ich&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP_5S_3e3tAhXLzqQKHeP3C3cQ6AEwAHoECAQQAg), bei [Bücher.de](https://www.buecher.de/shop/berlin/zwischen-du-und-ich/funk-mirna/products_products/detail/prod_id/60208155/) oder beim [Verlag dtv](https://www.dtv.de/buch/mirna-funk-zwischen-du-und-ich-28267/), oder bei diversen Buchhändlern wie [Thalia](https://www.thalia.de/shop/home/artikeldetails/ID149653838.html), [Lovelybooks](https://www.lovelybooks.de/autor/Mirna-Funk/Zwischen-Du-und-Ich-2739255630-w/) oder [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Zwischen-Du-Ich-Mirna-Funk/dp/3423282673).

In diesem Fall werden die Personalpronomen nämlich als Substantive verwendet, ähnlich wie im Strukturmodell der Psyche von Sigmund Freud. Er spricht dabei von einem *»Es«,* einem *»Ich«* und einem *»Über-Ich«,* die – Freuds These zufolge – gemeinsam die Psyche eines Menschen bestimmen sollen. Dabei sind *Es, Ich* und *Über-Ich* die Namen von drei Wesenszügen in der Persönlichkeit eines Menschen.

Ich interpretiere das Wenige, das ich bisher über das Buch gelesen habe so:
Die Protagonistin Nike trifft Noam, und beide müssen sich wegen ihrer jeweiligen Verwandten (Nikes Urgroßmutter, Noams Onkel) ohnehin schon mit einem Bündel fremdbestimmter Probleme herumschlagen. Als sie aufeinandertreffen, sehen sie sich gezwungen, sich auch noch mit dem jeweiligen Ich (im Freud'schen Sinn) auseinandersetzen. Da die Geschichte offenbar aus der Perspektive von Nike erzählt wird, ist das im Titel genannte *»Ich«* ihr eigenes Ich, also etwas, das ihre (Nikes) Persönlichkeit ausmacht. Noam hat natürlich sein eigens Ich, das seine Wesenszüge bestimmt. Aber Noams Ich wird aus Nikes Sicht zu dem Du, das im Titel steht. Und zwischen diesen beiden Ichs gibt es einen Unterschied, der im Buch thematisiert wird.

---

Die Präposition *zwischen* verlangt tatsächlich immer den Dativ, auch im Titel dieses Buchs. Aber der Dativ des Substantivs *»das Ich«* ist nicht <del>*»dem Mir«*</del> sondern *»dem Ich«:*

> Als sie aufeinandertreffen, müssen sie sich auch noch mit **dem** jeweiligen **Ich** auseinandersetzen.
> <sup>*Siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ich)*</sup>

Und der Dativ von *»das Du«* ist nicht <del>*»dem Dir«*</del> sondern *»dem Du«:*

> Aber Noams Ich wird aus Nikes Sicht zu **dem Du,** das im Titel steht.
> <sup>*Siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Du)*</sup>

Und tatsächlich kann man die Nominalphrase, die den Titel des Buches ausmacht, auch mit Artikeln schreiben:

> Zwischen dem Du und dem Ich
> Zwischen einem Du und einem Ich

Aus stilistischen Gründen, und vermutlich auch um die Phrase *»zwischen dir und mir«* in abgewandelter Form zu zitieren, hat sich der Verlag aber entschieden, keine Artikel im Titel zu verwenden.

Es wurde also keine Regel verletzt. Es ist nur nicht immer alles das, wofür man es anfangs hält. In diesem Fall sind die vermeintlichen Pronomen gar keine Pronomen, sondern Substantive.

Comment: Vielen Dank Herrn Schölnast für die Antwort und detaillierte Erklärung. Obwohl Ihre Niveau der Erklärung war sehr hoch, aber die Erklärung hat mir geholfen.